# How does doing a U- Substitution come out with this outcome?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I saw this on a website. I am working on Integrals and the U-Substitution didn't make sense.

The original problem was $\int$x/x+1$dx$

The U-Sub did u = x+1 , du = dx

then it gave me a $\int$u-1/u du...

How did the u-1 become on the numerator is my question?

Comment: $u = x+1$, so the numerator $x = u-1$.

Comment: Oh my! I can't believe I did not figure that out. Thanks a lot! @peterwhy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way it becomes easier to do this integral by writing it as
$$\int \frac{x+1-1}{x+1}dx=\int 1-\frac1{x+1} dx$$
The latter integral can easily be performed as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln{(x+1)}=\frac1{x+1}$$

Comment: Yea, but to obtain $\int\dfrac{dx}{x+1} = \ln (x+1) + C$, it is still by $u$-sub if done verbosely...